# E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu

This is my Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

When I do `sudo apt update`, the following error happened.

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
```

What is the reason please?

====update Sep 23 2022====

This worked for me:

```
mkdir ~/.apt-backup 
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list* ~/.apt-backup
```

Comment: The question should be moved to https://askubuntu.com/, you won't get any answer here as it is a programming related questions site.